# Changing a tex4ht span class using Confiig file

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, document-configuration

I have my Table of contents as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-2" id="leftCol">
   <div class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
       <h3 class="likesectionHead">Contents</h3>

       <div class="tableofcontents">
       <span class="chapterToc">1 <a href="#x1-20001" id="QQ2-1-2">Python Primer</a></span><br />
       <span class="sectionToc">1.1 <a href="#x1-30001" id="QQ2-1-3">Reshaping the future</a></span><br />
       <span class="subsectionToc">1.1.1 <a href="#x1-40001" id="QQ2-1-4">Exercises</a></span><br />
       <span class="subsubsectionToc"><a href="#x1-50001" id="QQ2-1-5">R-1.1</a></span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to access those sweet `<span class="subsectionToc">` and `<span class="subsubsectionToc">` to add things to them such as:

```
<li class="nav-header"> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userMenu">
    <span class="subsectionToc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>1.1.1 <a href="#x1-40001" id="QQ2-1-4">Exercises</a></span> 
    <ul class="list-unstyled collapse in" id="userMenu">
       <li class="active"> <span class="subsubsectionToc"><a href="#x1-50001" id="QQ2-1-5">R-1.1</a></span></li>
       <li><span class="subsubsectionToc"><a href="#x1-50001" id="QQ2-1-6">R-1.2</a></span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Without adding a `ConfigureEnv`.

I can't seem to find a way to access a specific span class using `\Configure`, does anybody know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely isn't easy. By default, `toc` produced by `tex4ht` isn't hierarchic, and we must use pretty complicated code to achieve it. This is borrowed from `tex4ebook`. First simple helper file, `hierarchictoc.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{hiearchictoc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\endinput
```

main purpose of this file is to enable us to use `\usepackage{hierarchictoc}` in the `.cfg` file, which in turn will include main file, `hierarchictoc.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{NavSection}{4}

\newbool{tocnoempty}

\newcount\navpoint
\def\stepnavpoint{\advance\navpoint by1\relax\the\navpoint}

% Commands for support of hiearchical table of contents
% Support for: chapter, section, subsection
\def\resettoclevels#1{%
\def\do##1{\csgdef{nav##1finish}{}}
\docsvlist{#1}
}
\def\usetoclevels#1{%
\def\do##1{\csuse{nav##1finish}}%
\docsvlist{#1}%
}
\def\finishtoclevel#1{%
\csgdef{nav#1finish}{\d:NavSection}
}
\def\closelevels#1{
\usetoclevels{#1}
\resettoclevels{#1}
}
% 1 - section type 2 - closed sections
\def\navsection#1#2{
\ConfigureToc{#1}%
{\closelevels{#2}%
\edef\spanclass{#1Toc}%
\a:NavSection\Ncx:Mark}
{\c:NavSection}
{}
{\b:NavSection%
\finishtoclevel{#1}%
}
}
\def\Ncx:Mark#1{%
\edef\:temp{#1}
\def\z@ro{0}
\ifx\:temp\z@ro\else#1\fi
}
%
\Configure{tableofcontents}{\HCode{<nav>\Hnewline<ul>}}{%
\usetoclevels{part,chapter,likechapter,section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}%
\HCode{</ul></nav>\Hnewline}}{}{}{}
% We need to configure TocLink
% Configuraion of entries
\resettoclevels{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
\navsection{part}{part,chapter,likechapter,section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{chapter}{chapter,likechapter,section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{likechapter}{chapter,likechapter,section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{section}{section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{likesection}{section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{subsection}{subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{likesubsection}{subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{subsubsection}{subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
\navsection{likesubsubsection}{subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
```

whats going on here? important is this macro:

```
\def\navsection#1#2{
\ConfigureToc{#1}%
{\closelevels{#2}%
\edef\spanclass{#1Toc}%
\a:NavSection\Ncx:Mark}
{\c:NavSection}
{}
{\b:NavSection%
\finishtoclevel{#1}%
}
}
```

which is called like:

```
\navsection{section}{section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}
```

this is direct configuration for each level in the `toc`. code configured with `\Configure{NavSection}` is inserted and children levels are closed as needed. You can configure `NavSection` in the `.cfg` file:

```
\usepackage{hiearchictoc}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{NavSection}{\HCode{<li><span class="\spanclass">}}{\HCode{</span><ul>}}{ }{\HCode{</ul></li>}}
\EndPreamble
```

it has four parameters. First is inserted at the beginning of `toc` entry. Note `\spanclass` command. Current class is stored here and you can use some conditionals to work with it. Second parameter is inserted after entry, as you can see, `<span>` element is closed here, and `<ul>` for choldren entries is inserted. Third parameter isn't interesting, it is code inserted between chapter number and link to section, it is space in our case. Last parameter is inserted when levels are closed.

For some sample file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Hello}
\section{world}
\subsection{hello, hello}
\subsection{hello, again}
\section{next section}
\end{document}
```

this is the result:

[image]

```xml
   <h2 class="likechapterHead"><a 
 id="x1-1000"></a>Contents</h2> <nav> 
<ul>     <li><span class="chapterToc">  1 <a 
href="#x1-20001" id="QQ2-1-2">Hello</a></span><ul>      <li><span class="sectionToc">  1.1 <a 
href="#x1-30001.1" id="QQ2-1-3">world</a></span><ul>      <li><span class="subsectionToc">  1.1.1 <a 
href="#x1-40001.1.1" id="QQ2-1-4">hello, hello</a></span><ul>  </ul></li>    <li><span class="subsectionToc">  1.1.2
<a 
href="#x1-50001.1.2" id="QQ2-1-5">hello, again</a></span><ul>  </ul></li></ul></li>    <li><span class="sectionToc">  1.2 <a 
href="#x1-60001.2" id="QQ2-1-6">next section</a></span><ul>
   </ul></li></ul></li></ul></nav>
```

I don't really understand how you want decide which classes to add to individual `<span>` elements, but it should be possible to do various tricks using `spanclass`, if you add some more detail

Comment: Thanks Michal, I hadn't ask for your help in months, and here you are saving me again. Your `tex4ebook` git seems very interesting, I don't know lua but I would like to help, I'll check it out. I just want to make some sections collapsible. Here is the beta site http://claudiordgz.github.io/GoodrichTamassiaGoldwasser/

Comment: @Claudiordgz my biggest pain with tex4ebook (and tex4ht as well) is documentation, so if you have any ideas how to improve it, it would be nice. the site looks really nice :)

Comment: Would you be interested in having a front webpage using github pages? Just give me some time to understand your project.

Comment: @Claudiordgz sure, it would be great!

Comment: ossom, I will get on it :D

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for this example. It's a shame it is so hard to find. I spent hours trying to figure out how to do this before i found this answer.